# Shadow simulator depends on non-existing libgazebo_ros_factory.so

Tags: ros, gazebo, shadow-robot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When starting Gazebo with the command "roslaunch sr_hand gazebo_arm_and_hand_motor.launch" I get this error:

```
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_factory.so: libgazebo_ros_factory.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:326 : Exception: Failed to load the World
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_factory.so: libgazebo_ros_factory.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Error Loading Gazebo
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:326 : Exception: Failed to load the World
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_factory.so: libgazebo_ros_factory.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


failed to cleanly remove [/tmp/gazebo-ebd-0] : [Directory not empty]
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 23426, exit code 255].
log files: /home/ebd/.ros/log/0c876ba2-dec0-11e0-8e01-0025b311be58/gazebo-2*.log
```

The promised log files are not created.

I checked ROS_ROOT/../stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_plugins/lib, and the file libgazebo_ros_factory.so is there in diamondback, but not in electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11207/shadow-simulator-depends-on-non-existing-libgazebo_ros_factory.so/) by [erikjber](https://answers.ros.org/users/254/erikjber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2011-09-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erikjber](https://answers.ros.org/users/254/erikjber/) on 2011-09-14**:
The empty example file included with Gazebo works fine:  roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-09-14**:
Is it only the Shadow simulator that fails? Can you load other simulations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Sorry about the delay in answering this thread.

Electric is not supported yet for the Gazebo simulation of our hardware (see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sr-ros-interface/+bug/844934)). I'll try to fix this shortly.

Cheers,

Ugo

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the gazebo_ros_factory was deprecated as we wrapped the functionalities into `gazebo/src/gazeboros.cpp`.

Look for and remove the plugin referring to **libgazebo_ros_factory** in your `.world` file.

Once [simulator_gazebo 1.4.5](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/ChangeList/1.4) debians are out, gazebo should continue to run without throwing and exiting (see [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/2176/care-o-bot-simulator-crashing-gazebo)).

On top of that, there are other bugs.  I've opened a [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5172) with a patch that makes things work.

[here's a snapshot of the working model](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13162022213554064.png), it seems some of the links have strange orientations (e.g. elbow flex).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erikjber](https://answers.ros.org/users/254/erikjber/) on 2011-09-16**:
Removed reference to plugin. Still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you cannot wait for Ugo to fix this, here are the 2 modifications we used to start the simulator (They may not solve your problem completely):

- in sr_hand/launch/gazebo/empty.world commenting out :

```
<!-- <controller:gazebo_ros_factory name="gazebo_ros_factory" plugin="libgazebo_ros_factory.so">
          <alwaysOn>true
          <updateRate>1.0
          <interface:audio name="dummy_gazebo_ros_factory_iface_should_not_be_here"/>
        </controller:gazebo_ros_factory> -->
```

- in sr_hand/launch/change this line :

```
<!-- spawn the arm model -->
 <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find sr_hand)/model/robots/xacro/shadowhand_motor.urdf.xacro'" />
 <node name="spawn_hand" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model shadowhand_motor" respawn="false" output="screen" />
```

---

Originally posted by [GuiHome](https://answers.ros.org/users/768/guihome/) with karma: 242 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erikjber](https://answers.ros.org/users/254/erikjber/) on 2011-09-16**:
I changed sr_hand/launch/gazebo_arm_and_hand_motor.launch. I also tried replacing the strings "shadowhand_motor" with "arm_and_hand_motor". Neither worked - gazebo crashes on or shortly after startup.